# How to get Testnet Tezos?

Tags: faucet, testnet

**Option 1)** Download the .json file from: https://faucet.tzalpha.net/

To activate the Test Tezos enter:

`tezos-client activate account alice with "tz1__xxxxxxxxx__.json"`

**Option 2)** An easy way to get (a small amount, currently 100) Test Tezos is this Telegram Bot:

Telegram username: @tezos_faucet_bot

[image]

Comment: Please convert this into a clear question and associated answer. How to get testnet tokens with 2 examples in the answer, 1 for faucet and 1 for bot would be helpful. Or if you only want this to be about the bot ask "Are there any bots or alternatives to the standard Tezos faucets for test networks?" and create the associated answer.